# $ sign in the middle of Rabbit MQ password does not work

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I have changed the password using rabbitmqctl command like below

rabbitmqctl change_password CPSCUser Waseem$1234
Changing password for user "CPSCUser" ...
...done.

Now when i login with the CPSCUser from the management console (http://10.201.127.29:15672/#/) it fails.

However if i put $ at the end of the password it works

rabbitmqctl change_password CPSCUser Waseem1234$
Changing password for user "CPSCUser" ...
...done.

Management console login works with CPSCUser/Waseem1234$

Is there a way i can have special characters inside the password like Waseem$1234

If this is not possible then i will have to add a lot of validation rules for password in my code.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation we found this is an issue, more details here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/66

Comment: Thanks... This issue is reported my me... RabbitMQ team has confirmed that they have a bug in their rabbitmqctl script... I will post an update here once this bug is fixed... Thanks old_sound